# Is it possible to go from Form 2 to Form 1 in qt?

Tags: qt

I created two windows in QT. When a button is clicked on the first window, the program sends the user to the second window. If the user clicks a button on the second window, can he/she be able to go back to the first window? If so, how would the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `QWizard`.  It has all this functionality built in.

Or you could just make a tabbed form.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#details

> The `QWizard` class provides a framework for wizards.
>
> A wizard (also called an assistant on Mac OS X) is a special type of
>   input dialog that consists of a sequence of pages. A wizard's purpose
>   is to guide the user through a process step by step. Wizards are
>   useful for complex or infrequent tasks that users may find difficult
>   to learn.
>
> `QWizard` inherits `QDialog` and represents a wizard. Each page is a
>   `QWizardPage` (a `QWidget` subclass). To create your own wizards, you can
>   use these classes directly, or you can subclass them for more control.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows exactly what was asked for:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w1;
    w1.setWindowTitle("Form 1");
    QHBoxLayout f1;
    w1.setLayout(&f1);
    QPushButton nextButton("next");
    w1.layout()->addWidget(&nextButton);
    w1.show();

    QWidget w2;
    QHBoxLayout f2;
    w2.setLayout(&f2);
    QPushButton prevButton("prev");
    w2.layout()->addWidget(&prevButton);
    w2.setWindowTitle("Form 2");
//    w2.show();
    w2.move(w1.geometry().right()+30, w1.geometry().top());

    QObject::connect(&nextButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &w2, SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(&nextButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &w1, SLOT(hide()));

    QObject::connect(&prevButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &w1, SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(&prevButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &w2, SLOT(hide()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Also be sure to read about QWidget attributes, such as:

```
Qt::WA_QuitOnClose
```

> Makes Qt quit the application when the last widget with the attribute
>   set has accepted closeEvent(). This behavior can be modified with the
>   QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed property. By default this
>   attribute is set for all widgets of type Qt::Window.